# How to place background image and text inline in Bulma CSS?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am creating a portfolio page. I am using Bulma. The thing I want is to place the background image and text inline.

Here's the code:

```
<section class="hero is-halfheight upload-descr" style = "height: 37em">
        <div class="hero-body">     
            <div class="container">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <hr class = "rm-descr-bar" style = "float: left;"></hr>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h1 class = "title">
                    Loren Ipsum
                </h1>
                <div class="content rm-has-medium-size">
                    <p class = "upload-descr-exp" aria-live = "polite" aria-atomic = "true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing<br />elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br />Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<br />ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br />ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

The thing I want is background image shifted at right in `<div class = "container">`. However it gets cropped. I messed up with height and width of the container. This affected the text inside the container i.e. it was not vertically centered anymore. Please help.

I want to achieve this:
[image]

I tried:

```
<section class="hero is-halfheight upload-descr section" style = "height: 37em">
        <div class="hero-body container" style = "background: url('/img/pic.png') no-repeat right; background-size: contain;">     
            <div class="container">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <hr class = "rm-descr-bar" style = "float: left;"></hr>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h1 class = "title">
                    Loren Ipsum
                </h1>
                <div class="content rm-has-medium-size">
                    <p class = "upload-descr-exp" aria-live = "polite" aria-atomic = "true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing<br />elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br />Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation<br />ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br />ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

I achieved the thing I wanted after trying above code. However, on decreasing viewport size, background image and text appears on above other maybe they got vertical and horizontal centered. Please help me. How can I place background image and text next to each other without any bugs?

Here's the bug:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you keep the the div container containing the background image and the div container having the text part seperate as sibling containers? This way, you can make use of display:flex on section and they won't overlap and will be aligning side by side at all resolutions of your viewport.

Comment: There's no </hr> delete it, try     background-size: cover;

Comment: Do you want it for full page?

Comment: No @Liamm12. 37em div probably.

Comment: Do you want the background like this, I can change the text to fit what you want https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/h006func/

Comment: I want the background image in right @Liamm12

Comment: @Liamm12 That solution was of no help if it doesnt solve the OP's query.

Comment: @Sanjay - Did u ever solve this problem ? What was the fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Idea

- Left side **text** and right side the **image**
- Give all the same background color

### Example

(The image ratio is about 4:3. Change CSS according to your needs.)

```css
.mySection {
  background-color: #F93122;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.myHero {
  padding: 50px 0 50px 75px;
}

.myHero .hr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 15px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.myHero h1 {
  font-size: 50px
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .myHero {
    padding: 50px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<section class="mySection">
  <div class="columns is-vcentered">
    <div class="column is-5-tablet is-5-desktop">
      <div class="myHero">
        <div class="hr"></div>
        <h1>Loren Ipsum</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta a et ipsa voluptates in velit rem minus nihil, blanditiis nisi, quidem tempore quos qui quas. Blanditiis hic dolorem fugiat? Blanditiis!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-7-tablet is-7-desktop">
      <figure class="image is4by3">
        <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/29gedzq.png">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Hint**

[Bulma#image](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/image/)

Answer (score -3):

You used two times container class as per my thought that is why you getting this bug. Are you want change background color red to and img ?